# If $f(x)+\frac{f'(x)}{x}\to0$ then $f(x)\to0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I honestly have no idea how to solve this one. Can we use the mean value theorem?

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(f(x)+\frac{f'(x)}{x}\right)=0 \implies \lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$$

Answer (score 6):

A general method is to consider the expression converging to zero as a function of $x$ and to express $f$ in terms of it. Here, let $$g(x)=f(x)+\frac{f'(x)}x,$$ then $$x\mathrm e^{x^2/2}g(x)=x\mathrm e^{x^2/2}f(x)+\mathrm e^{x^2/2}f'(x)=\left(\mathrm e^{x^2/2}f(x)\right)',$$ hence, for every $x\geqslant c\gt0$, 
$$\mathrm e^{x^2/2}f(x)=\mathrm e^{c^2/2}f(c)+\int_c^xt\mathrm e^{t^2/2}g(t)\,\mathrm dt.$$ Now, the usual $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ approach works, or rather, here, the $\varepsilon$-$x_0$ approach.

Fix some positive $\varepsilon$. There exists some finite $x_0\gt0$ such that, for every $x\geqslant x_0$, $|g(x)|\leqslant\varepsilon$. Thus, using $c=x_0$ in the identity above and the triangular inequality, one gets $$\mathrm e^{x^2/2}|f(x)|\leqslant\mathrm e^{x_0^2/2}|f(x_0)|+\int_{x_0}^xt\mathrm e^{t^2/2}|g(t)|\,\mathrm dt\leqslant c_0+\varepsilon\int_{x_0}^xt\mathrm e^{t^2/2}\,\mathrm dt,$$  with $c_0=\mathrm e^{x_0^2/2}|f(x_0)|$, thus, $$\mathrm e^{x^2/2}|f(x)|\leqslant c_0+\varepsilon (\mathrm e^{x^2/2}-\mathrm e^{x_0^2/2})\leqslant c_0+\varepsilon \mathrm e^{x^2/2},$$ which implies $$|f(x)|\leqslant c_0\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}+\varepsilon.$$
The first term on the RHS converges to zero hence $$\limsup_{x\to\infty}|f(x)|\leqslant\varepsilon.$$ This holds for every $\varepsilon\gt0$ hence the proof is complete.

---

*Exercise:* Follow closely the steps above to show that, for every functions $a$ and $b$ such that $a(\ )\geqslant\alpha\gt0$ uniformly and $\int^x\frac{a}b\to+\infty$ when $x\to+\infty$, if $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}a(x)f(x)+b(x)f'(x)=0,$$ then $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0.$$ The question above is when $a(x)=1$ and $b(x)=1/x$ for every $x\gt0$.

Comment: thanks for sharing your proof and exercise :)

Answer (score 2):

Let us suppose that the hypothesis is verified. Then we prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$. The exact regularity property of $f$ is not stated by OP: here I am supposing it to be continuous and everywhere differentiable (continuity of the derivative is not required).

First we prove the following property of the function $f$:

> Let $\varepsilon > 0$; then there is $x_0$ such that, for every $x \geq x_0$, if $|f(x)| < \varepsilon$ then $|f(y)| < 2\varepsilon$ for all $y \geq x$.

In order to prove this lemma let us use the hypothesis and take $x_0$ large enough so that for each $x \geq x_0$ we have
$$
\left| f(x) + \frac{f'(x)}{x} \right| < \varepsilon. \qquad (*)
$$
Now suppose that there is $y$ such that $|f(y)| \geq 2\varepsilon$ and take the smallest of such $y$, which exists by continuity and is strictly larger than $x$. Then, by continuity, it actually holds that $|f(y)| = 2\varepsilon$. We can also assume that $f(y)$ is positive; if it is not, we reason with $-f$ instead of $f$. Then $\frac{f'(y)}{y} < -\varepsilon$, so $f'(x) < 0$. This implies that just before $y$ the function $f$ is larger than $f(y) = 2\varepsilon$, but this is absurd because we took $y$ to be the smallest value greater than $x$ with that property. This establishes the lemma.

From the lemma it follows that if there are arbitrary large values of $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$, then $|f|$ is definitively smaller than $\varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$. Then $f$ has limit zero.

So the only missing case is when $f$ is definitively positive or negative. As before the two cases are symmetrical and we cover only the positive one. Take $f$ definitively bigger than a constant $2\varepsilon > 0$. Then find $x_0$ such that for $x \geq x_0$ there holds $(*)$ above. It follows that $f'(x) < x \varepsilon \leq x_0 \varepsilon$, so that $f(x)$ must eventually descend under $2\varepsilon$, in contradiction with the assumption. This proves that in this case too $f$ must tend to zero and closes the proof.

Comment: Apparently there are much tougher approaches than mine around. The only advantage of my answer is probably the fact that it just relies on elementary tools (the definition of limits and continuity). Very nice to learn other answers!

Answer (score 1):

Let's change the variable $t=x^2/2$ , and $\tilde f(t)=f(x)$
Then $f'(x)=\tilde f'_t x$. Thus we can rewrite 
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}(\tilde f(t)+\tilde f^\prime(t))=0;
$$
No let's define
$$
\tilde f(t)+\tilde f'(t)=g(t)
$$
and solve $f$ as functional of $g$.
We can write 
$$
\tilde f=C e^{-t}+\int_0^t e^{\tau-t}g(t) d\tau
$$
Since $g(t)\to 0$ we have $\tilde f(t)\to 0$

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(f(x)+\frac{f'(x)}{x}\right)=0$, so for all $\varepsilon >0$ exists $y$, that for $x>y$:

$$f(x)+\frac{f'(x)}{x}<\varepsilon$$

So (because $x>0$):

$$f(x)x+f'(x)<\varepsilon x$$

Now multiply both sides by $e^{x^2/2}$:

$$f(x)xe^{x^2/2}+f'(x)e^{x^2/2}<\varepsilon x e^{x^2/2}$$

It's equal:

$$(f(x)e^{x^2/2})'<\varepsilon x e^{x^2/2}$$

And:

$$(f(x)e^{x^2/2})'-(\varepsilon e^{x^2/2})'<0$$

So function $(f(x)-\varepsilon)e^{x^2/2}$ is decreasing. So:

$$(f(x)-\varepsilon)e^{x^2/2}<(f(y)-\varepsilon)e^{y^2/2}$$

Dividing both sides by $e^{x^2/2}$:

$$f(x)-\varepsilon<(f(y)-\varepsilon)e^{y^2/2-x^2/2}$$

Let $x \to \infty$. Then:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)-\varepsilon < \lim_{x \to \infty}e^{y^2/2-x^2/2}=0$$

The same way  $-\varepsilon<f(x)+\frac{f'(x)}{x}$ we show that $0<\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)+\varepsilon$. It's for all $\varepsilon$, so $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=0$